# PHP - autorizar apenas uma area do website ao usuario

Tags: php, sql

Tenho uma barra de pesquisa que só apenas pessoas cadastradas podem aceder. até ai tudo bem o meu codigo esta a funcionar, o problema a cada pesquisa na barra de pesquisa as credencias são pedidas, ou seja, o meu codigo requer sempre que faça login. mas aquilo que eu pretendo é que só peça para fazer log in quando a pessoa tiver feito logout.

Meu código:

```
<?php

include("config.php");

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
        echo "you are not logged in,please click here to <a href='memberarea.html'>Login</a>";
    } else{

 $query = $_GET['query']; 


    $min_length = 3;


    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 


        $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$query);

      $row_results = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM books WHERE `Title` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `category` LIKE '%".$query."%'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));


        if(mysqli_num_rows($row_results) > 0){ 

            while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($row_results)){

                echo "<p><h3>".$results['Title']."</h3>".$results['category']."</p>";

            }

        }
        else{ 
            echo "No results";
        }

    }
    else{ 
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Na pergunta, as credenciais são *pedidas* ou *perdidas*? Você está chamando `session_start()` no início do código?

Answer (score 1):

quando usei isso em php fazia assim em todas as paginas

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["logado"])) {
   $_SESSION["logado"] = false;
   session_start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para iniciarmos uma session, usamos a função session_start(). 
Para um bom funcionamento, ela não pode estar depois de nenhum OUTPUT de dados (echo, print, códigos HTML, etc.). É recomendável que esteja na primeira linha do código.

Se no seu include("config.php"); `session_start()` não for chamada

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 include("config.php");
```